# Retrieve username of the currently authenticated LDAP user from a bound connection

Tags: ruby, ldap

I'm using ruby's net-ldap library. I'm writing some code that receives a connection object on which a successful bind() operation has already been completed, meaning an LDAP user has already supplied a username and password and logged in successfully.

I now want to run some code to check if the user belongs to a specific LDAP group. I actually have this code working already. But what I'm wondering is if it is possible in LDAP to find the DN or username of the user that authenticated with the current connection. The username was already required to log in, but this occurred in some other code that I don't have access to. Here is some sample code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net-ldap'

connection_options = {
  :encryption => :simple_tls,
  :host => SERVER,
  :port => PORT,
  :base => BASE,
  :auth => {
    :username => "#{username}@#{DOMAIN}",
    :password => password,
    :method => :simple
  }
}
connection = Net::LDAP.new(connection_options)
if connection.bind
  puts "Authentication succeeded"
  # now find the username (again) given a valid connection object
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a control that can be used to discover the authenticated identity called the authorization identity request control. The answer is returned in the response, called the authorization identity response control. The controls are defined [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3829).

Comment: Thanks. This helps, although, unfortunately the ruby library I'm using hasn't implemented this functionality yet. If/when I get it working, I'll post it here.

Comment: I am no Ruby expert, but a quick perusal of rubygems shows support for controls.

Answer (score 0):

And there is also a 'who am I' extended operation.